# Quota with Git on Gitosis?

Tags: git, quota

I'm using Gitosis to host some Git repositories.

Is there any possibility to get a quota on the Git repositories?

Comment: Also, Gitosis is a dead project. If you need to make this sort of change, it's probably best to migrate to Gitolite, which already has finer-grained permission structure.

Answer (score 0):

Gitosis does not support quotas.  If your filesystem of choice supports per-directory quotas, this would be one way to achieve the same behavior.